# ¿Como poner puntos suspensivos solo si acorto la cadena?

Tags: php

Como puedo poner los puntos suspensivo solo al acortar la cadena es decir en mi caso el límite de substr es 70, me gustaría que aparezcan los puntos solo al superar el límite porque aparecen siempre.

```
<?php echo htmlentities(substr($row['value'], 0, 70). '......');?>
```

Comment: Con un if o con ?:, strlen() y el substr() que estás usando :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un condicional `if` (tal como te indican en los comentarios) y el método `substr()` para recortar la cadena y lo concatenas con `...`, ejemplo:

```
<?php 
    $value = $row['value'];
    if(strlen($value) > 70) {
        $value = substr($value, 0, 70) . '...';
    }
    echo htmlentities($value);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes obtener el resultado que buscas midiendo tu cadena de caracteres, comparándola con 70 y mostrarla completamente en caso de que no los alcance, o recortándola y concatenando unos puntos suspensivos si los supera.

Todo ello te quedará mucho más compacto haciendo uso de un operador condicional ternario `condicion ? si se comple ? si no se cumple`.

Así:

```
<?php 

echo htmlentities(
    strlen($row['value'])>70 
    ? substr($row['value'], 0, 70).' ...'
    : $row['value']
);

?>
```

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._ No olvides explicar cómo funciona el código :)

Comment: @padaleiana ¿¿En serio?? Tan mala no será cuando no han tardado mucho en copiármela... :D Venga, vale, la explico un poco :)

Answer (score 2):

Si tus cadenas tienen caracteres acentuados o especiales, es conveniente usar las funciones para [cadenas de caracteres multibyte](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mbstring.php)

> Cuando se manipulan cadenas de caracteres (trim, split, splice, etc.) en una codificación multibyte, es neceario utilizar funciones especiales, ya que dos o más bytes consecutivos pueden representar un único carácter en tal esquema de codificación. Si, de lo contrario, se usa una función que no considera caracteres multibyte con la cadena de caracteres, es probable que falle al detectar el comienzo o el final del carácter multibyte, y que se termine con una cadena de caracteres corrupta que probablemente pierda su significado original.

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php 
echo $valor = $row['value'];
if (mb_strlen($valor) > 70) $valor = mb_substr($valor, 0, 70) . '...';
echo htmlentities($valor);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está resuelto, pero dejo una versión un poco más elaborada que puede servir a otros como *snippet* en sus desarrollos. Puede cortar la cadena dejándola truncada con `mb_substr`; o si se requiere algo más elegante, que la frase termine con una palabra completa sin sobrepasar el límite.

En la parte del `else`, se divide la cadena y se recorre palabra por palabra en un `for`. Si la longitud de `$result` + la longitud de la palabra sobrepasa el límite, se rompe el ciclo. De lo contrario se concatena a `$result` un espacio y la palabra actual y regresa al siguiente ciclo del `for`.

Nota: Para PHP < 7.1 quitar las [declaraciones de tipos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.declarations.php) en la función.

```php
<?php
function trncStr(string $str, int $maxL, bool $fullW=false): string {
    if(mb_strlen($str) <= $maxL) {
        $result = $str;
    } elseif($fullW === false) {
        $result = mb_substr($str, 0, $maxL) . '...';
    } else {
        $result = '';
        $count  = -1;
        foreach(mb_split(' ', $str) as $item) {
            $count += mb_strlen($item) + 1;
            if($count > $maxL) {
                $result .= '...';
                break;
            }
            $result .= ' ' . $item;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Algunas pruebas:

```php
echo trncStr("Una cadena corta", 25);
echo trncStr("¿Dónde está la guía de programación?", 21);
echo trncStr("¿Dónde está la guía de programación?", 21, true);
```

Resultado:

```
Una cadena corta
¿Dónde está la guía d... 
¿Dónde está la guía...
```